# Image showing offline but not online

Tags: html, css, ajax, image

I am finishing a website for a photographer and when I upload it online a picture that shows perfectly well when I test the site offline is missing. I know my path is correct and case sensitive. Here is the address of the website:

http://maxruiz-parana.com

and you need to click on the menu link "bio". By the way, these sections are loaded using ajax, not sure if this is relevant. Under "bio" you will see a short text next to what should be the picture of the photographer. You can check the code and I guarantee you the picture is in the correct folder and the name is written exactly like it:

```
<div id="paragraphBio">

  <p>Max Ruiz vit et travaille à Paris
    comme photographe<br />et réalisateur.
    Son travail a été exposé un peu partout<br />
    (Arles, Houston Photo Fest, etc…)</p>
</div>

<img  id="maxImage" src="Images/MaxRuiz.jpg">
```

Any ideas much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I see the photo of the photographer. I'm also getting a javascript error in the console.

Comment: http://maxruiz-parana.com/Images/MaxRuiz.jpg exists and is working fine online yeah. Are you sure your paths are correct? Try doing `/Images/MaxRuiz.jpg` instead of `Images/MaxRuiz.jpg` to make sure it's loading from the document root on a local machine

Comment: ok. thanks for this. I see the picture too now using chrome and firefox but not safari, so that that at least. My problem is only on safari

Comment: I'm seeing the image on Safari. Maybe you have a cache issue?

Comment: I see the image of the photographer but its messed up a tad, I attached a screenshot of what I see. https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5L1P.png

Comment: I am also seeing it (Firefox Mac)

Comment: it was a cache issue. thanks a lot guys